# Content Type of a Very Specific Extension * .asd

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Through a system developed in MVC5 I am loading in my database SQL Server in VarBinary type files with extension `*.asd`. This extension corresponds to the file type

Reflectance Spectra of ASD Terraspec (* .asd, * .sco)

This is a curve that reads a very specific application **Indico Pro**. The idea is to be able to visualize the file in a corresponding view. I used the application / octet-stream type with negative result.

Code:

```c#
 public ActionResult verASD() {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DocumentacionPrueba;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT VALUE FROM FILEDETAILS WHERE NAME ='"+ vid +"' AND HOLEID='"+ vholeid +"'" ;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            return File((byte[])dr["VALUE"], "application/octet-stream");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Using Google Chrome the error is:

> **Plugin is not Supported**

```html
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">        
    <section class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <embed src="@Url.Content("~/Documentos/verPDF?value1=@ViewBag.codCarpeta&value2=RC-RC-002")" class="form-control input-lg mb-md" style="height:860px;" type="application/octet-stream" />        
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </div>
```

If you have a idea please tell me.